# Error: Login sessions require session support

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have installed express-session yet i'm getting Error: Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use `express-session` middleware?
the passport.authenticate doesn't works because of this
index.js

```
const ejs = require("ejs");
const url = require("url");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const toastr = require('express-toastr');
const Profile = require('./models/Profile.js');
const passport = require("passport");
const { customAlphabet } = require('nanoid');
const express = require("express"),
      path = require('path')
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const { Notyf } = require('notyf')
const { connect } = require('mongoose');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const MemoryStore = require("memorystore")(session);
const methodOverride = require('method-override')

connect(process.env.mongodb);

const initializePassport = require('./utils/passport-config.js')

initializePassport(
  passport,
  email => Profile.find({ email_id: email }),
  id => Profile.find({ user_id: email })
)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  session({
    store: new MemoryStore({ checkPeriod: 86400000 }),
    secret: "#@%#&^$^$%@$^$&%#$%@#$%$^%&$%^#$%@#$%#E%#%@$FEErfgr3g#%GT%536c53cc6%5%tv%4y4hrgrggrgrgf4n",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  }),
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());
app.use(toastr());

app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')))
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')))
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  }),
);

const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    req.session.backURL = req.url;
    res.redirect("/login");
  } catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
  }
};

app.get('/', async function(req, res){
 res.render('index.ejs', { url: req.url })
});

app.get('/login', async function(req, res){
  if (req.session.backURL) {
    req.session.backURL = req.session.backURL;
  } else if (req.headers.referer) {
    const parsed = url.parse(req.headers.referer);
    if (parsed.hostname === app.locals.domain) {
      req.session.backURL = parsed.path;
    }
  } else {
    req.session.backURL = "/";
  }
 res.render('login.ejs', { url: req.url })
});

app.get('/signup', async function(req, res){
 res.render('signup.ejs', { url: req.url })
});

app.get('/newshop', async function(req, res){
 res.render('shopcreate.ejs', { url: req.url })
});

app.get('/profile', async function(req, res){
 res.render('profile.ejs', { url: req.url })
});

app.get('/settings', async function(req, res){
 res.render('settings.ejs', { url: req.url })
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
}), async (
  err,
  req,
  res,
  next,
) => {
  try {
    await console.log(req)
    if (req.session.backURL) {
      const backURL = req.session.backURL;
      req.session.backURL = null;
      res.redirect(backURL);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

passport-config.js -

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    console.log(email)
    const user = getUserByEmail(email)
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' })
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id))
  })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

Comment: You set up session support _after_ initializing Passport...

Comment: @CherryDT ok now i have edited the code and added it after setting up session but i still the authenticate doesnt works and gets redirected to the "failureRedirect"

Comment: That's a different question then!